# MySQL error 1248: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, alias, mysql-error-1248

I run into this issue with the query

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(
  id , '|' , calc_eu , '|' , ( 
        SELECT 
          CASE 
            WHEN texto IS NULL THEN '' 
            ELSE texto 
          END 
        FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              texto_es AS texto
            FROM 
              bdgui_diccionario_unidad 
            WHERE 
              bdgui_diccionario_unidad.id = bdgui_unidad.text_eu_id 
          )
      )
  ) SEPARATOR '|' ) AS unidad 
FROM 
  bdgui_unidad ;
```

If I add an alias to subquery **AS alias** I got another error

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(
  id , '|' , calc_eu , '|' , ( 
        SELECT 
          CASE 
            WHEN texto IS NULL THEN '' 
            ELSE texto 
          END 
        FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              texto_es AS texto
            FROM 
              bdgui_diccionario_unidad 
            WHERE 
              bdgui_diccionario_unidad.id = bdgui_unidad.text_eu_id 
          ) AS alias
      )
  ) SEPARATOR '|' ) AS unidad 
FROM 
  bdgui_unidad ;
```

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'bdgui_unidad.text_eu_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: you could replace that `case` with a simple `IFNULL(texto, '')`

Comment: What do you want to group? Please provide some example with in and out data you need to select.

Comment: Finlay I had to take another approach and re-factorize the query. 
This is my working version.

    SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
          id,
          '|',
          calc_eu,
          '|',
          (SELECT 
              CASE
                WHEN texto_es IS NULL 
                THEN '' 
                ELSE texto_es 
              END
          FROM
            bdgui_diccionario_unidad 
          WHERE bdgui_diccionario_unidad.id = bdgui_unidad.text_EU_id)
        ) SEPARATOR '|'
      ) AS unidad 
    FROM
      bdgui_unidad ;